discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ask" is not found
Even thought I initiated async ask, and I asked !ask ("How are you?'), it still gave the issue of command ask not found. Plz help
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from gtts import gTTS
import asyncio
import os
from transformers import pipeline

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='distilgpt2')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')
async def ask(ctx, *, question):
    response = generate_response(question)
    await ctx.send(response)
def generate_response(prompt):
    response = generator(prompt, max_length=100)[0]['generated_text']
    return response

bot.run('MTIxxxxxxxxxxx')


it may need @bot.command before async def ask(...)

never show token in questions.

It needs @bot.command() or @bot.command('ask') before async def ask(...)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')
    
#@bot.command('ask')
@bot.command()
async def ask(ctx, *, question=None):
    if question:
        response = generate_response(question)
    else:
        response = "Your forgot question: `!ask question`"
    await ctx.send(response)

Documentation: Commands
